# Building ios corePlot with Xcode 5.0 using a Dependent project scenario

Tags: ios, xcode, core-plot, armv7, build-settings

I am new to IOS and am writing an ios 7.0 app that uses coreplot (latest version 1.3). I had the "Build active architecture" set to YES - so during the development, I did not run into any linking problem (I used static linking method as described at https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications

Then I built and deployed on my device (iphone 4, ios 7). It worked fine - I dont remember if it asked to change build settings or not. Today morning, when I tried to run the same code on simulator it started giving me linker error. After doing some research, I realized I need to set the build for active architecture to No and rebuild the core plot using "dependent project install" strategy. 
I am  stuck at the point where I need to set the header files search path. The compilation fails to detect the header file. The coreplot is in a directory CorePlot_1.3.

The main linking error reads as 
"ignoring file /Users/rmenon/Documents/Developer/MoneyTrail/MoneyTrail/libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/rmenon/Documents/Developer/MoneyTrail/MoneyTrail/libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a (3 slices)"

As part of my attempt to solve this, I tried to load the coreplot project separately, change the architecure to Stndard (armv7 nd armv7s) and tried to build it. I get two deprecation errors below. Any help in getting me compile this library for ios 7 so I can use the same setting in debug and device would be really appreciated! Thank you!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to update to a newer version of Core Plot. It has been updated to work with Xcode 5 and iOS 7, but we haven't done a release with those changes yet. You can pull the latest code with Mercurial or wait for the next release, which should be soon (within the next week or so).

Comment: Thanks Eric! I actually did try to download the source yesterday but it was "hanging" at "adding file changes" (after around 2 hours, I killed it). Will retry today.

Comment: Downloaded the latest code - hopefully it would fix the problem.

Comment: Was able to build successfully from source. I built the coreplot separately in xvode5 after changing the architecture setting to include arm64 (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913906/xcode-5-and-ios-7-architecture-and-valid-architectures). Then linked the generated libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a to the main project and built that project.