# How to make framework support architecture x86_64?

Tags: ios, architecture, frameworks, arm64

I made my own framework and everything was fine. But when Apple releases 64bit architecture when another project uses 64-bit architecture my framework doesn't want to compile. 
When I changed architecture of project just armv7 and armv7s - it complies good but when i changed architecture back to arm64 - it produces error -

```
(null): "_OBJC_CLASS_$MYFramework", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in RWAppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

So I've changed architecture of framework to include arm64, but error in my project still there

Is there another way to support arm64?

I added a screenshot of support architectures of framework 
[image]

Comment: x86_64 is Intel architecture. Have you set proper target arch?

Comment: Yes. I updated question so you will see

Comment: Why don't you just use 32bit architecture? 64bit CPU from Apple was just Marketing issue rather real feature. No one will see any performance boost for next 2 years until they make phone with 4+GB of RAM.

Comment: i need it cause projects the uses arm64 as architecture will not compile my framework.

Comment: I guess there always 32bit version of projects. As it was main platform for many years.

Comment: You are right but with the newest XCode there is other statndart architecture that includes 64-bit. My framework doesn't want to compile in projects that include this architecture

Comment: I think its hard to help you without looking in to makefiles.

Comment: can you give me right examples of makefiles please?

Comment: I don't have any as I don't have any active IOS development. You should have. You can send on my private email account if you don't want to share here. BTW have you tried : use -v to see invocation?

Answer (score 0):

From error description you provided I can see that:

During linking phase for Intel 64bit architecture _OBJC_CLASS_$MYFramework symbol was not found. Which is quite strange as you sure you compiling for arm architecture. Maybe you should revise Makefiles of your framework?

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913906/xcode-5-and-ios-7-architecture-and-valid-architectures) Shell you make target IOS7 32bit?