# Selection of the ios on the simulator Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode5

As you can see in the image I have the IOS 5.1 version installed in Xcode for the simulator, but surprisingly I can select it in a project but not in the other.

[image: http://postimg.org/image/jp184gmlz/]

Why is this happening? Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project's deployment version is probably set to iOS 6 or 7.

Comment: I have changed it to 5.1.1 and the IOS 5.1 option isn't still in the simulator menu

Comment: If the simulator is 5.1, why are you changing your deployment target to 5.1.1?  Set it to 5.1, not 5.1.1.  Also restart Xcode as sometimes it gets confused.

Comment: Because I get this Error when I try to set it to 5.1 ("Applications including an arm64 slice are not compatible with versions of iOS prior to 5.1.1") and I ignore what is arm64 used for, even how could disable it, I am new with Xcode :(

Comment: Set to 5.1.1 only otherwise you should drop down the 64bit support. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913906/xcode-5-and-ios-7-architecture-and-valid-architectures/18914141#18914141

Comment: Thank you very much! I have changed that architectural parameter and now I can see the IOS 5.1

Answer (score 0):

Check that the deployment target is set to the lowest version of iOS that you want to support. Select your project in the Project Navigator and then check the Deployment Info section under the General tab:

[image]

Comment: I have changed it to 5.1.1 and the IOS 5.1 option isn't still in the simulator menu

Comment: @AndoniMuruamendiaraz Try setting it to 5.1, not 5.1.1.

Comment: 5.1 or 5.1.1 doesnt matter. If you want to build a combined binary including 64 and 32bit, deployment target should be 5.1.1 or above

Answer (score 0):

Because You have installed ios 5.1 Simulator 
In second image that is your 1st project it is display both ios5.1 and ios7 both because you have set its deployment to 5.1,

and for second project deployment target is selected only ios7, so..

set project's deployment version to iOS 5.1 , and check.

Comment: I have changed it to 5.1.1 and the IOS 5.1 option isn't still in the simulator menu

Comment: If the simulator is 5.1, why are you changing your deployment target to 5.1.1? Set it to 5.1, not 5.1.1. check Jim's comment.