# Xcode: Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 error

Tags: ios, xcode5, restkit

In my Xcode 5 project I use RestKit for REST communication.
Everything works fine with the simulators, but generating the ipa file, I get the following error:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/joseph/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXXXXXXX-gdwdekevxtdfivfpsnmyykeqhulk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRestKit.a, missing required architecture arm64 in file /Users/joseph/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXXXXXXXXXX-gdwdekevxtdfivfpsnmyykeqhulk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRestKit.a (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKRelationshipMapping", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in classname-xxx.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKObjectMapping", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in classname-xxx.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKRequestDescriptor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in classname-xxx.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKObjectManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in classname-xxx.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKResponseDescriptor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in classname-xxx.o

  "_RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass", referenced from:
      -[classname-xxx classname-Method] in classname-xxx.o
      -[classname-xxx classname-Method] in classname-xxx.o
      -[classname-xxx classname-Method] in classname-xxx.o
      -[classname-xxx classname-Method] in classname-xxx.o
      -[classname-xxx classname-Method] in classname-xxx.o
  "_RKMIMETypeJSON", referenced from:
      -[classname-xxxinitWithURLBase:timeOut:] in classname-xxx.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).
```

If in RestKit project, I change in "Build Settings" -> "Architectures" the "Standard architectures (ARMv7, armv7s)" by Standard architectures (including 64-bit) (ARMv7, armv7s, arm64) option, everything compiles fine . Is this correct?, Does not bring any result, I have to change some other settings.

Comment: Did you try changing in **your** project and in **RestKit** "Build Settings" -> "Architectures" to "Standard architectures (ARMv7, armv7s)"?

Comment: I change in my project and in RestKit to "Standard architectures (including 64-bit) (ARMv7, armv7s, arm64)".

Comment: So whats the question? you build succeeds but archive doesn't?

Comment: My question is, if it brings no disadvantages or if I have to add some other configuration. Because RestKit has by default"Standard architectures (ARMv7, armv7s)" on  "Build Settings" -> "Architectures".

Comment: What I wrote to you below answers your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It just means you are building your project also for 64bit (iPhone 5s) and nothing to worry about, see this link for some more explanations:
[Xcode 5 and iOS 7: Architecture and Valid architectures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913906/xcode-5-and-ios-7-architecture-and-valid-architectures)

Answer (score 7):

1. Select Restkit project
2. Set the **Build Active Architecture Only** to `No`

[image: Build Active Architecture Only]

Answer (score 3):

Just change in RestKit project -> Build Settings -> Architectures to Standard Architecture (armv7, armv7s, arm64). After that everything should work.

Comment: @MiBrock sorry, I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

ios sdk 9.3

into your build setting of app.xcodeproj valid architecture: armv7 armv7s Build Active architecture : No

Clean and build , worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case i forgot to add sqlite library in my project.
After adding library from Linked framework and library the build was successful.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same/similar issue implementing AVPictureInPictureController and the issue was that I wasn't linking the AVKit framework in my project.

The error message was:

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVPictureInPictureController", 
referenced from:
   objc-class-ref in yourTarget.a(yourObject.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
```

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
The Solution:

Go to your Project
Select your Target
Then, go to Build Phases
Open Link Binary With Libraries
Finally, just add + the AVKit framework / any other framework.
Hopefully this helps someone else running into a similar issue I had.