# Unable to build iOS release in Visual Studio Hybird Application (Cordova)

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I am building a Corodva application in Visual Studio 2015. I am able to run the app on both simulator and the connected iPhone device and I see .ipa file generated in the Cordova project /bin/iOS/Debug directory.

Now, I am trying to generate a release version of the .ipa iOS app that should be located in /bin/iOS/Release.

The problem is that whenever I try to run the project under the 'release' + 'iOS' + 'Local Device' configuration in Visual Studio, I get the following errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)   CustomerCordovaApp2015  C:\B8akWorkspace\B8akProject\B8akSolution\CustomerCordovaApp2015\clang  1

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/566/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build  Command failed with exit code 2: {1}    CustomerCordovaApp2015  C:\B8akWorkspace\B8akProject\B8akSolution\CustomerCordovaApp2015\Error  1

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/566/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2 CustomerCordovaApp2015  C:\B8akWorkspace\B8akProject\B8akSolution\CustomerCordovaApp2015\ERROR building one of the platforms    1

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/566/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build  Command failed with exit code 2 CustomerCordovaApp2015  C:\B8akWorkspace\B8akProject\B8akSolution\CustomerCordovaApp2015\MDAVSCLI   1
```

Additionally, the output in Visual Studio states that "You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project." Here is the relevant lines form the output panel:

```
.
.
.
.
1>  Ld build/B8ak\ بيتك.build/Release-iphoneos/B8ak\ بيتك.build/Objects-normal/arm64/B8ak\ بيتك normal arm64
1>      cd /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/566/cordovaApp/platforms/ios
1>      export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
1>      export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/.taco_home/node_modules/taco-remote-lib/1.0.0/node_modules/taco-remote-lib/ios/node_modules/ios-sim/build/release:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
1>      /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk -L/Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/566/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device -F/Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/566/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device -FB8ak\ بيتك/Plugins/msopentech.azure.NotificationHub -filelist /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/566/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/B8ak\ بيتك.build/Release-iphoneos/B8ak\ بيتك.build/Objects-normal/arm64/B8ak\ بيتك.LinkFileList -dead_strip -weak_framework CoreFoundation -weak_framework UIKit -weak_framework AVFoundation -weak_framework CoreMedia -weak-lSystem -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -framework AssetsLibrary /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/566/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device/libCordova.a -framework CoreGraphics -framework MobileCoreServices -framework WindowsAzureMessaging -weak_framework Social -weak_framework MessageUI -framework CoreLocation -weak_framework SystemConfiguration -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/566/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/B8ak\ بيتك.build/Release-iphoneos/B8ak\ بيتك.build/Objects-normal/arm64/B8ak\ بيتك_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/566/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/B8ak\ بيتك.build/Release-iphoneos/B8ak\ بيتك.build/Objects-normal/arm64/B8ak\ بيتك
1>ld : warning : ignoring file B8ak بيتك/Plugins/msopentech.azure.NotificationHub/WindowsAzureMessaging.framework/WindowsAzureMessaging, missing required architecture arm64 in file B8ak بيتك/Plugins/msopentech.azure.NotificationHub/WindowsAzureMessaging.framework/WindowsAzureMessaging (3 slices)
1>  Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
1>    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SBNotificationHub", referenced from:
1>        objc-class-ref in NotificationHub.o
1>  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
1>clang : error : linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
1>
1>  ** BUILD FAILED **
1>
1>
1>  The following build commands failed:
1>      Ld build/B8ak\ بيتك.build/Release-iphoneos/B8ak\ بيتك.build/Objects-normal/arm64/B8ak\ بيتك normal arm64
1>  (1 failure)
1>  Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/566/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build-release.xcconfig,-project,B8ak بيتك.xcodeproj,ARCHS=armv7 armv7s arm64,-target,B8ak بيتك,-configuration,Release,-sdk,iphoneos,build,VALID_ARCHS=armv7 armv7s arm64,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/566/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/566/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
1>  Command finished with error code 2: /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/566/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build --device,--release
1>ERROR building one of the platforms : error : /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/566/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
1>  You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
1>  Failed to build app for buildNumber 566: /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/566/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
1>Error : Remote build error from the build server Build failed with error /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/566/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2: {1}
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

And here is the Mac terminal output with no meaningful error that I can spot:

```
IBRAHIM-ALHUSSAINs-Mac-mini:~ IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN$
IBRAHIM-ALHUSSAINs-Mac-mini:~ IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN$
IBRAHIM-ALHUSSAINs-Mac-mini:~ IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN$
IBRAHIM-ALHUSSAINs-Mac-mini:~ IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN$ remotebuild --secure false
remotebuild
Copyright (C) 2014 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
1.0.1

Warning: No server modules selected. Defaulting to configuration "modules": {"taco-remote": { "mountPath": "cordova"} }
Build Retention initialized with baseBuildDir /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds, maxBuildsToKeep 20
Initialized BuildManager with baseBuildDir /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds; maxBuildsInQueue 10; deleteBuildsOnShutdown true; allowsEmulate true; nextBuildNumber 20711
Remote build server listening on [http] port 3000
New build request submitted:
/build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=4.3.0&cfg=release&options=--device&loglevel=warn
{ 'accept-language': 'en-US',
  host: '192.168.8.102:3000',
  connection: 'close',
  'transfer-encoding': 'chunked' }
Build will be executed under: /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/20712
Saving build request payload to : /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/20712
Saved upload to /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/20712/upload_20712.tgz
express deprecated req.host: Use req.hostname instead ../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/remotebuild/node_modules/taco-remote/lib/server.js:88:96
POST /cordova/build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=4.3.0&cfg=release&options=--device&loglevel=warn 202 17977.116 ms - 717
GET /cordova/build/tasks/20712 200 6.083 ms - 717
Extracted app contents from uploaded build request to /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/20712/cordovaApp. Requesting build.
Taking 20712 as current build
GET /cordova/build/tasks/20712 200 14.648 ms - 68648
GET /cordova/build/tasks/20712 200 75.858 ms - 68678
GET /cordova/build/tasks/20712 200 5.350 ms - 68685
GET /cordova/build/tasks/20712 200 6.710 ms - 68685
GET /cordova/build/tasks/20712 200 3.103 ms - 68670
GET /cordova/build/tasks/20712 200 5.005 ms - 68670
GET /cordova/build/tasks/20712 200 3.343 ms - 68670
GET /cordova/build/tasks/20712 200 4.864 ms - 68670
GET /cordova/build/tasks/20712 200 3.119 ms - 68670
GET /cordova/build/tasks/20712 200 4.597 ms - 68670
GET /cordova/build/tasks/20712 200 2.738 ms - 68670
GET /cordova/build/tasks/20712 200 2.895 ms - 68670
GET /cordova/build/tasks/20712 200 2.787 ms - 68670
GET /cordova/build/tasks/20712 200 2.811 ms - 68670
GET /cordova/build/tasks/20712 200 3.549 ms - 68670
GET /cordova/build/tasks/20712 200 2.728 ms - 68670
GET /cordova/build/tasks/20712 200 10.458 ms - 68670
GET /cordova/build/tasks/20712 200 2.671 ms - 68670
GET /cordova/build/tasks/20712 200 2.645 ms - 68670
GET /cordova/build/tasks/20712 200 9.239 ms - 68670
GET /cordova/build/tasks/20712 200 2.867 ms - 68670
GET /cordova/build/tasks/20712 200 2.611 ms - 68670
GET /cordova/build/tasks/20712 200 4.430 ms - 68670
GET /cordova/build/tasks/20712 200 4.024 ms - 68670
GET /cordova/build/tasks/20712 200 23.758 ms - 68670
GET /cordova/build/tasks/20712 200 4.739 ms - 68670
GET /cordova/build/tasks/20712 200 4.178 ms - 68670
GET /cordova/build/tasks/20712 200 3.713 ms - 68670
Done with currentBuild. Checking for next build in queue.
GET /cordova/build/tasks/20712 200 3.835 ms - 68973
GET /cordova/build/tasks/20712/log 200 390.930 ms - -
```

I tried to clean the solution and reset the Cordova cache but I cannot determine the source of the issue.

Comment: The underlying error message is buried in your second output, but it is clear: "`_OBJC_CLASS_$_SBNotificationHub` is not defined in arm64". When I search for that error I see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926632/xcode-5-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64-error

Comment: Have you solved this issue ?