# How to use Superpowered lib in Swift project

Tags: c++, ios, swift, objective-c++

I want to make an app in Swift that simply record via the mic of the iPhone and then play the sound recorded.

For that, I'd like to use the lib Superpowered that is a static library with header files.

For that, I tried to drag and drop the .a and headers files in my project (Xcode create for me a bridging header file), add the .a in "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" in Xcode > Target > General (and so in Xcode > Target > Build phases > "Link Binary With Libraries" too) and index the .h files path in Xcode > Target > Build Settings > Search Paths > Library Search Paths.

But with that I have the error "ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64"
Exactly the same as here [XCode: Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926632/xcode-5-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64-error) and I tried all the solutions that I found on the web for that, still no way to compile.

SO !

Superpowered gives us a sample app to show how to mix Objective-C++ and use their lib within a Swift project (Here's a link to the git if you want https://github.com/superpoweredSDK/Low-Latency-Android-Audio-iOS-Audio-Engine).

Here is some screenshots of the sample project with what I understand and what I don't :

[image: Bridging header file Superpowered]

The Bridging-Header-File with the prototypes of the methods of the lib that I want to use within my Swift code (I don't like this but if it's the only way...).

[image: ViewController file]

The viewController file where the code in Swift is, and where I can create a Superpowered object thank's to the Bridging-Header-File, and call the methods that I've put in it.

[image: .mm file]

And wtf I don't even understand why this Objective-C++ file is here and what it contains. It comes out from nowhere, not even their lib files.

So with this sample project in mind, I've created my own project, here is some screenshots :

[image: Briging-Header-File]

The same Bridging-Header-File that in the sample project except that I include `SuperpoweredIOSAudioIO.h` so I can use `SuperpoweredIOSAudioIODelegate`.

[image: viewController]

My viewController file where the code in Swift is, and where I can create a Superpowered object thank's to the Bridging-Header-File, and call the methods that I've put in it.

Until here, it's great, except that I can't for exemple create a `SuperpoweredRecorder` object. If I try to include the `SuperpoweredRecorder.h` file in my Bridging-Header-File I have these errors :

[image: errors]

So I saw that it is because `SuperpoweredRecorder.h` includes some .cpp files and I have to create a wrapper for cpp (a little bit like I did with the bridging header, no ?) but that includes a .h and a .mm file and I don't know what I have to put in that .mm file (the code of `SuperpoweredRecorder.cpp` ? But I don't have access to it)

So yes, I'm a little bit confused with all that stuff, can you help me to understand how can I use all the Superpowered lib in my Swift project please ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I said in comment to @OmniProg, I had a little conversation with the CTO of Superpowered that helped me a lot to find the solution below.

So, as Swift cannot interact directly with C++ but can with Objective-C, I had to create objects in Objective-C++ (.mm file, a mix between C++ and Objective-C) that wrap C++ classes of the lib Superpowered.

Here is an example with the SuperpoweredRecorder object from the lib :

[image: SuperpoweredRecorderWrapped.h]

Here I create a .h file where I prototype my wrapper with the name `SuperpoweredRecorderWrapped`, and I also prototype in it all the methods of the `SuperpoweredRecorder` of the lib that I want to use.

[image: SuperpoweredRecorderWrapped.mm]

Then I create a new .m file that I rename .mm and I implement `SuperpoweredRecorderWrapped` on it.
I import both `SuperpoweredRecorderWrapped.h` and `SuperpoweredRecorder.h`.
I create a `SuperpoweredRecorder` object as property named `_wrapped` and in my methods, I call the corresponding method of the `_wrapped` object.
With that, when I'll call `start` of a `SuperpoweredRecorderWrapped` in my Swift code, this one will call `start` of `_wrapped`, a `SuperpoweredRecorder` object. See the trick ?

[image: Bridge-Header]

And finally I include all the wrapped classes in my Bridging-Header, like that I can instantiate my wrapped objects from Swift.

**NOTE**: All the C++ code HAVE to be in .mm files, that's why I make my `#include` of .h that contains C++ code in my .mm file and not in my .h file.

Comment: I am using a similar trick to wrap C++, however, the problem is that some of the dependencies could not be found, such as: 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "_AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey", referenced from:
     __ZL9makeAssetPKcb in libSuperpoweredAudioOSX.a(ipodreader.o)

Check this issue for detail:
https://github.com/superpoweredSDK/Low-Latency-Android-iOS-Linux-Windows-tvOS-macOS-Interactive-Audio-Platform/issues/481

Comment: hi @YoanGJ, I need your help while Integrating SuperpoweredFrequencyDomain in swift project...

Comment: Hi @Mr.Ahtazaz I didn't use this library for several years now so I don't know if I can help but I'll try... tell me

Comment: Thanks for your kind response @YoanGJ.  As integrate it successfully, but i need help while implementing SuperPoweredEcho

Comment: Can you give me your Mail @YoanGJ

Comment: I have sen you a message. @YoanGJ

Answer (score 3):

I haven't programmed in Objective-C++, but I do have experience with C, C++, Objective-C, and Swift, so here are some observations and ideas based on looking at the Superpowered SDK and sample code.

A bridging header lets Swift interface directly with Objective-C, and since Objective-C is a strict superset of C, this implies interfacing with C as well.  However, you cannot interface directly with C++, and that's where Objective-C++ comes to the rescue.  From what I'm seeing you can mix Objective-C and C++ code in Objective-C++, which allows Objective-C to use C++ classes.

Now on to some specifics.

The bridging header in the SuperpoweredFrequencies example that you looked at introduces a *new* Objective-C class, `Superpowered`, which is not part of the library, but of the example, and is implemented in `Superpowered.mm`.  It is an Objective-C++ file, because `Superpowered` calls some C++ code.

Looking at `Superpowered.mm`, you will see that it imports Objective-C headers:

```
#import "SuperpoweredFrequencies-Bridging-Header.h"
#import "SuperpoweredIOSAudioIO.h"
```

as well as C and C++ headers:

```
#include "SuperpoweredBandpassFilterbank.h"
#include "SuperpoweredSimple.h"
```

We could have used `import` instead of `include` for C++ code, too, but they are probably using `include` just to emphasize that it is C++ code. Looking at `SuperpoweredBandpassFilterbank.h`, we see that `SuperpoweredBandpassFilterbank` is a C++ class.  It is used in `Superpowered.mm` by the `Superpowered` Objective-C++ class, see the `filters` member, which is a pointer to a `SuperpoweredBandpassFilterbank` object.

In the project you attempted to build, I see where the `Superpowered` interface is declared in the bridging header, but I don't see an implementation.  The failure to `#import SuperpoweredRecorder.h` is due to `SuperpoweredRecorder.h` being a C++ header.  The `#include` should be in your Objective-C++ (.mm) file, it's useless in the bridging header, since Swift can't make sense of C++ anyhow.

Hopefully this is helpful. Welcome to the world of C++.

Comment: After time and a little conversation with the CTO of Superpowered, I've understood all that you explain here and with that I've found the solution that I'll post in few minutes. But things are clear now, thank's !

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit surprised that you would have to provide prototypes of method.
I used Objective C libraries in my Swift project before and I only had to add the header files in my bridging header.

See example from my project. The bridging header contains just that:

```
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

#import "QTouchposeApplication.h"
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
#import <VungleSDK/VungleSDK.h>
```

Comment: Yes, I have no problem neither when I use Objective-C libraries but here, the lib is written in C++ and that makes things more painful to set.

Comment: You're right, I didn't get that from your original post, but looking at @OmniProg's answer it makes sense now. Thanks for posting your solution!