# iOS add dlib to project, linker error

Tags: ios, dlib

I have this error while following [this tutorial](https://oktapodi.github.io/2017/05/29/getting-started-with-dlib-on-ios.html):

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /project/lib/libdlib.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (arm64): /project/lib/libdlib.a
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_cblas_dgemm", referenced from:
      dlib::blas_bindings::cblas_gemm(dlib::blas_bindings::CBLAS_ORDER, dlib::blas_bindings::CBLAS_TRANSPOSE, dlib::blas_bindings::CBLAS_TRANSPOSE, int, int, int, double, double const*, int, double const*, int, double, double*, int) in DlibWrapper.o
  "_dgesvd_", referenced from:
      dlib::lapack::binding::gesvd(char, char, long, long, double*, long, double*, double*, long, double*, long, double*, long) in DlibWrapper.o
  "_dgesdd_", referenced from:
      dlib::lapack::binding::gesdd(char, long, long, double*, long, double*, double*, long, double*, long, double*, long, long*) in DlibWrapper.o
  "_USER_ERROR__missing_dlib_all_source_cpp_file__OR__inconsistent_use_of_DEBUG_or_ENABLE_ASSERTS_preprocessor_directives", referenced from:
      _dlib_check_consistent_assert_usage in DlibWrapper.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What can I do?

Comment: add Build Settings -> Architectures to Standard Architecture (armv7, armv7s, arm64).

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik In dlib project or in my project?

Comment: check both .....

Comment: see this for ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926632/xcode-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64-error

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik didn't help, same errors :(

Comment: @EvgeniyaTveritinova You can try with older version of dlib, where the flag -std=c++11 not required in Build settings ->other complier flag for dlib project.

Answer (score 2):

add accelerate framework

for iOS and macOS platform, the framework include the symbols.