# How to build single binary with 32 bit & 64 bit in xcode 6

Tags: build, app-store, xcode6, itunes, archive

I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21200669/how-single-app-binary-supports-64-bit-and-32-bit-apps.) stack overflow solution but even though i am getting below warning.

```
Missing 64 bit support.Starting February 1, 2015, new iOS apps uploaded to the App Store
must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK, included in Xcode 6 or later.
To enable 64-bit in your project, we recommend using the default Xcode build setting of 
“Standard architectures” to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit code.
```

I have chosen

```
 Project - Target - Build settings - Architectures - Standard Architectures(armv7,arm64).
```

eventhough i am getting above warning. please help me out.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Had the same issue. It looks like adding 'arm64' to the Valid Architectures (also under build settings) solved it.

Comment: This answer is ludicrous -- how would anybody know that!? -- and totally correct. Thanks.

Comment: make sure you type arm64, not armv64... doh!

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you want to check this out: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html

Comment: How exactly does this help?