# Xcode 5.1.1 archiving app results in build errors

Tags: ios, xcode, 64-bit, archive, ios7.1

I've been trying to build my application. Whilst it runs fine on 32 bit simulators, it will not build for any 64 bit device and it will not archive. When I try to do these things, it throws up a load of errors about cyclic dependencies in CoreFoundation, Darwin etc. pictured below:

[image: Errors when attempting to archive]

I have tried numerous solutions that I found on the web, including changing the architectures to support only armv7 and armv7s and targeting older versions of iOS, but most of these answers are from older versions of Xcode and were posted months ago. Nothing I try seems to work. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: this is not Xcode issue this is you implemented parse or other third-party code that not well setup it it's library not build with `arm64` in to you project.

Comment: What might be in the third-party code to cause this? How would I find it? It still builds for older devices

Answer (score 0):

You have `Architectures` set to `Standard Architectures`, which includes `arm64` in newer versions of Xcode, but have `Valid Architectures` set to only include armv7 and armv7s. This needs to be exactly opposite:

Set Architectures to

```
$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)
```

And set Valid Architectures to

```
arm64 armv7 armv7s
```

[a good reference from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316310/how-to-stop-xcode5-1-building-for-64bit/22350904#22350904)

[another good link from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913906/xcode-5-and-ios-7-architecture-and-valid-architectures)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Following this advice allowed me to build my project to run on 64bit simulators, but it still won't archive or run on my actual device; same errors. Any ideas?

Comment: Try cleaning the project and deleting all derived data perhaps? What errors are you still getting?

Comment: I've done these things numerous times. Still the same errors. I ended up copying the files over into a new project and that did the trick. A bit tedious but oh well. Thanks anyway.