# Enabling iOS device for development on XCODE6

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-provisioning

**Where in xcode 6 or the developer site can I enable my device as a development tool?**

The answers I've found online seem to be out of date.

I noticed xcode 6 has had a bit of a UI shuffle. When I plug my new iOS device in, I can't find the 'Use for development' button

I have 2 devices
Device A - iPhone 4s
Device B - iPhone 6 (this is what I am trying to configure)

I have confirmed the following
My certificate is valid
My development profile is valid
My development profile now includes Device B
The valid development profile has been installed in Device B
I can still deploy to Device A

It just feels like Device B doesn't know it should be used for development.

The actual build errors are
**neon_matrix_impl.c**
Unknown register name 'q0' in asm

Within 2 methods

```
void NEON_Matrix4Mul(const float* a, const float* b, float* output )
void NEON_Matrix4Vector4Mul(const float* m, const float* v, float* output)
```

Comment: That error message doesn't seem to be anything to do with the device being enabled for development.  It sounds like invalid assembler code being generated

Comment: @Paulw11 ok thanks, are you familiar with the settings? There is a ton of Build Settings I don't normally tamper with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316310/how-to-stop-xcode5-1-building-for-64bit/22350904#22350904) solved my problem when I realised this was the first time I was trying to deploy to a 64bit device