# How to resolve Cyclic dependency error in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am getting "**Cyclic dependency in module 'Foundation': Foundation -> UIKit -> QuartzCore -> Foundation**" Error when i build my project.how to resolve it. i have refer below links answer but its not work for me.I have remove derived data and quit xcode many times still i am getting this error.

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316310/how-to-stop-xcode5-1-building-for-64bit/22350904#22350904)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316310/how-to-stop-xcode5-1-building-for-64bit/22350904#22350904)

[image]

Comment: are u going to import your.h file in AppDelegate?

Comment: have you imported .m file instead of .h file anywhere? it happens...

Comment: What is the name of the source file that is generating that error message?

Comment: @rokjarc no i have imported .h file

Comment: @Droppy Error message come from UIKit and Foundation Framework not from classes.

Comment: Yes, but it was generated during the compilation of a file, no?

Comment: @Rushabh - Are you using .pch file ?

Comment: @gagansharma yes i am using .pch file

Comment: @Rushabh - Please see my answer below I have edited, might help you.

Comment: Try to move your `#import`s from .h files into .m files as much as you can.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can break the cyclic import by `#import` one in the `.m file`,or you can learn to use `@import` the new feature which use the module map made dependency.

Answer (score 1):

This might generalise your situation - You have imported class B into class A and now you are importing class A in class B, so in second case rather than importing class A in B use forward declaration -
Use @class A in class B (second case).
If you are using .pch file, you might be adding Framework or Headers twice.
In .pch file and in other files as well.
In your case try removing the UIKit and Foundation frameworks either from .pch file or from other place where you  are adding them repetitively.