# Architecture not supported - Xcode error

Tags: xcode, ios7.1, xcode5.1

I'm getting these errors whenever I'm trying to run my code on iPad device. Can't seem to figure out the solution here. Tried changing build configurations but it doesn't work. As I have to support for upcoming iOS releases for my app, I'm using SDK6.1 in Xcode 5.1 with deployment target set as iOS 7.1. [image][image]
Tried this solution [Xcode 5 and iOS 7: Architecture and Valid architectures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913906/xcode-5-and-ios-7-architecture-and-valid-architectures) but not working for me. Help!

Comment: What architecture do you have set for your target/configuration in your build settings?  What do you have set as valid architectures?

Comment: @phillip : Architectures - Standard architectures (armv7,armv7s,arm64)
Valid Architectures - arm64 armv7 armv7s

Answer (score 1):

You are probably compiling for arm64. I don't know if `arm/types.h` is set up to handle it, but you could try changing

```
#elif defined(__arm__)
```

to

```
#elif defined(__arm__) || defined(__arm64__)
```

for that include. Or remove `arm64` from "Valid Architectures" in build settings (including pods and subprojects).

Comment: Yes, iOS SDK 6 doesn't compile on arm64 architecture which is resulting in such compiler errors. So I removed the arm64 arch from build settings which worked for me :)

Also in another possible scenario, I tried the architecture code from SDK 7 into SDK 6 (change the above #elif condition for arm64); although it resolved the errors but it needed to be modified in a large number of classes to get going...