# Xcode Validating App: No architectures?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, validation

i using xcode 5.1 and i would like to validate my product. Here is the error, that i get:

> No architectures in the binary. Lipo is failed to detect any architectures in the bundle executable

I have Standard Architectures in the Build Settings and armv7 and armv7s in Valid architectures(i tried even with all of them) and Build active architectures is set to No.
I have no idea what happening here. I think if i can't resolve this I'll Distribute it without Validation... Please help me

My Deployment target is 7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your target deployment target and Architectures.

Kindly refer this link as well [Xcode 5 and iOS 7: Architecture and Valid architectures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913906/xcode-5-and-ios-7-architecture-and-valid-architectures)

Comment: My deployment target is 7.0 and i already said architectures. I think nothing wrong here.