# MobFox build crashes x86_64 mach o linker error

Tags: ios, mobfox

I am currently receiving the problem that i cannot build my iOS App for my iphone 5s anymore. I am always receiving an apple mach o linker error, because the MobFox SDK was not build for arm64. We are currently using the version 5.0.0, is there an update available that fixes this issue?
I know that I can get the SDK and could compile it on my own, but I do not know where to set the build settings there either, because there is no Architecture area in the build settings.
https://github.com/mobfox/MobFox-iOS-SDK

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just download the latest version of the MobFox SDK from the MobFox website if you have an account.

Most importantly, you should add `-ObjC` in linker flags.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look on the links in the mobfox and google ad mob website, you'll see that the adapter is not updated anymore from 08/04/2013...

Answer (score 0):

Click on your Project Name in Project Navigator(available in Left side)

Get MobFox SDK that supports

BuildSettings->type architecture in search area-> double click on Valid Architecture

and change according to your needs.

eg:

armv64,

armv7,   - related to IOS 7.

armv7s.  - related to IOS 7.

also refer this link it may help you

[Xcode 5 and iOS 7: Architecture and Valid architectures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913906/xcode-5-and-ios-7-architecture-and-valid-architectures)