# Apple Mach-O linker errors While Archiving My project

Tags: ios, facebook, xcode5, google-plus, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to archive my First iOS Project and I get the following errors. It seems like there is something bugged with the Facebook SDK and Google Plus SDK which i have used for Authentication. I have come across similar questions on stackoverflow but none's solutions helped me. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
<pre>
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in LoginViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogger", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in LoginViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLQueryPlus", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in LoginViewController.o
  "_kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin", referenced from:
      -[LoginViewController getInfoForGoogle] in LoginViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLServicePlus", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in LoginViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPPURLHandler", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPPSignIn", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in LoginViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in LoginViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
</pre>
```

Comment: Which version of the Google+ SDK are you using? Make sure it is at least 1.5.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The framework you are using is not arm64 ready, ie not for 64bit devices, you can either check if an updated framework is available, or exclude arm64 that from your build

Set the architecture in build settings to Standard architectures(armv7,armv7s)

[Xcode 5 and iOS 7: Architecture and Valid architectures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913906/xcode-5-and-ios-7-architecture-and-valid-architectures)