# Xcode 5.1.1 Not compatible with versions of iOS prior to 5.1.1

Tags: xcode5

This post on [Valid Architectures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913906/xcode-5-and-ios-7-architecture-and-valid-architectures) describes how to disable ARM64 so that your app will validate when iOS5 is targeted. The error message explicitly states that iOS 5.1.1 is a valid deployment version but in Xcode 5.1.1 that is not an option in the Deployment Target section—just 5.1. Is there an editable file somewhere where we can change the values in the drop down?

Does it even make any sense to try change the value in Xcode, rather than just disabling ARM64?

iOS 5.1.1 is the most recent version of iOS that the original iPad runs and I’m still targeting them so I’d like to deploy to them without impacting the performance on newer devices.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the Architectures to $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) and it validates. When I changed it back to the default, Xcode prompted me to change my iOS Deployment Target to 5.1.1 and I said OK. I don’t get the error when I validate.

I think, but I have not tried it, that you can also edit the values in Xcode. If you open the project settings with the version editor, you can see the Deployment target and change it in the code.