# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 iOS swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am working on a project with the Swift programming language and I am trying to use some code from some older Objective-c projects. I have created the bridge file and imported the headers that I need but I get the following error, which I know it has to do with linking some framework, but even when I added CoreGraphics as an added framework it still appears. Any ideas?

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CGPointMake", referenced from:
      _CGPointAdd in SKActionEffects-669E235BD7235D6A.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Thanks

**UPDATE:** setting the BaseSDK did not do the trick. This is what my build settings are like with xcode6.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913906/xcode-5-and-ios-7-architecture-and-valid-architectures set the BaseSDK to iOS

Answer (score 26):

Check if the "Target Membership" of your files are appropriate.

[image: ss]

Comment: This was it...saved me hours, awesome answer dude. I was adding files through a folder reference where I should have been just adding them in groups! Thanks!!!

Comment: @md_develop Can you ellaborate what this means? I have the same error but am not sure where to find the target membership. I'm assuming its somewhere in the project settings

Comment: @Unome I added screen shot. It's not the project setting but the file property.

Comment: i have the same error. However, I cannot select the target membership. It is gray and un-selectable. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you selecting `.h` file? Select `.m` or `.swift` file.

Comment: @md_develop In my case, I'm using ScriptingBridge in swift, and using a generated .h file (which is supposed to NOT have a .m file) and so I can't select membership

Comment: This i think has the quality to be the accepted answer i've been trying to figure out what went wrong for the last 3 hours thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that adding a class to test target just to test it is a good idea. In my case checking "Allow testing Host Application APIs" made a difference.

[image: Targets > YourApplicationUnitTests > Testing]