# Publishing my iOS app fails with "Certificate expired" even though I renewed my certificate

Tags: ios, certificate

When I publish the IPA, this error appears:

> Certificate expired

This happens even though I renewed my certificate and it is valid until December 2019.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Certificate Expired check goes against the certificate that was used in creating the Distribution Provisioning Profile that you are signing the app with for release.  If you created your Distribution Provisioning Profile using the old certificate which is now expired, you will need to create a new Distribution Provisioning Profile that is based on the new certificate, then, sign the Archived IPA file with that Distribution Provisioning Profile.  That should solve your problem.

Comment: this my certificate renew https://imgur.com/H9OK2JK how can creat a new certificate file .p12 with ios_distribution.cer

Comment: The way I do it is download the certificate by clicking the Download button.  Then, drag the downloaded file to your KeyChain app on the Mac. (open the keychain app and just drag the downloaded file into it and drop).  That will install the cert in your keychain.  Then, in the Apple Developer's console, scroll down and click on Distribution Provisioning Profiles.  Then click the + sign to add a new one.  Choose Distribution, choose your new certificate and save.  Download to your computer and drag it to XCode.  Change the Build Signatures to the new Distribution Provisioning Profile.

Comment: thanks have you video to explain this method thanks

Comment: thanks .... I've seen it before ... I want to explair more my problem ... first I creat my certificate in 2017 I have some apps in appstore ... in decembre 2018 I renew my certificate ... and I find a problem with apps update because my certificate is renew and when I publish update of one apps in animate cc I get error ... The certificate is exipred in 2017

Comment: When you build an app to release an update, you need to sign it with the latest certificate and you need to provision it with a distribution provisioning profile that uses that same certificate.  The first thing is create the new certificate, which you have done.  Then, you need to download that certificate and put it in your Keychain application on your Mac computer.  If you still have your old expired certificate on that computer, you should delete it from Keychain, so that it doesn't get confused with the new one.

Comment: Next, you need to create a new Distribution Provisioning Profile in your developer's console.  It will ask what type, pick for distribution on the App Store.  It will ask which App ID this is for, pick it from the list.  It will ask which certificate to use, choose the new one.  Once the profile has been created, download it and drag and drop it into your XCode.  Then, open your App in XCode, go to the Build Settings (if you have Automatic Signing turned on, try turning it off), then under the Signing Build Setting, select Distribution for Both Release settings.  Then build.

Comment: hello can you give me a free time to see this problem ... this my email ... raskourbina@gmail.com

Comment: the question now is how can I work with certificate.p12 update to update my apps

Comment: how can I renew certificate.p12 not  ios_distribution.cer
thanks

Comment: A certificate.p12 is just an extract of a certificate that is in the keychain app. After you download the ios_distribution.cer file, either double-click it, or drag and drop it into the Keychain Access app on your Mac computer.  That should install the certificate in your Keychain.  Then, in Keychain Access app, highlight My Certificates, scroll down until you find your new certificate, then highlight it and open the File menu and choose Export Items... in the Save As dialog, be sure the file format is .p12, and give it a name and save.  https://docs.airship.com/platform/ios/getting-started/

Comment: thanks to get me the best information... I do all this info it's work ... I have this error.. ERROR ITMS-90725 "SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the IOS 12.0.
All IOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the IOS 11 SDK or later, included in Xcode 9 or later.
Further, starting March 2019 , all IOS apps submitted to the Apps Store must be built with the IOS 12.1 SDK or later, included in Xcode 10.1 or later.

Comment: That just means that you need to download XCode 10.1 or later and recompile your app targeting iOS 12.1 before you can submit it.  Your current build version targets iOS 12.0.  Hope that helps!  If you have new questions, you should submit them as new StackOverflow questions, rather than extending one question with additional ones in the comments, and go ahead and accept an answer to this question if it solved your problem.  Good Luck!

Comment: my app has been uploaded but I get this error from apple developer " Xcode 10 doesn't support deployment targets lower than 8.0. You will either need to update the deployment target, or alternatively, if you need a lower target you can reinstall Xcode 9.4.1"

Comment: my system is macOS mojave version 10.14.4

Comment: There are two different build settings of importance.  One is Deployment Target, usually the minimum iOS version that is supported.  Yours must be lower than 8.0, you need to set it to 8.0 or later.  The other setting is for Base SDK which needs to be 12.1 or later.

Comment: hello ... first i will thank you for your time to answer my questions... I want to tell that this error " " appeared to me when I added Adobe AIR SDK & Compiler but when I add add only Adobe AIR 32 SDK the problem does not appear,,

Comment: what that mean " Yours must be lower than 8.0, you need to set it to 8.0 or later. "

Comment: hello again .. what does mean this problem "Invalid architectures - This app has invalid architecture, and may have been built with invalid build settings or incompatible tools. Try rebuilding the app with the latest Xcode version. If you are using third party development tools, contact the provider.
." i get this problem from developer apple .. thanks

Comment: See the answer in this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913906/xcode-5-and-ios-7-architecture-and-valid-architectures

Comment: You can build iOS apps in Adobe Animate?  If so, I don't know where you would make those setting changes.  In XCode, there is a Build Settings area, and in that area, there is a setting for Architectures, you want to select  Standard Architectures (armv7, armv7s).  That will address the error that you are getting from the Apple Developer portal.

Comment: thanks man my problel is solved it's work now perfectly thanks agin